# combining multiple geojson files w tsv and preserving property with topojson

Tags: d3.js, topojson

i'm trying to do many things w topojson… combine 2 geojson files w 1 tsv, join on ELECT_DIV n NAME, promote that to the id, and keep 2012_POP from the tsv.

here's the command i'm using:

`topojson -o electorates.json -e 2012_oz_population.tsv --id-property ELECT_DIV,NAME -p 2012_POP -s .0000005 --allow-empty -- electorates.geojson region.geojson`

ELECT_DIV is in electorates.geojson. it is getting set as the ID on all the features, but each one is not getting the proper 2012_POP from the join with the tsv. however, at the top level, electorates and region are getting the last value of 2012_POP from the tsv, so it's joining in some way...

any ideas on what i'm doing wrong? do i need to do this in more than one topo command?

thanks!

UPDATE W REQUESTED INFO

2012_oz_population.tsv
`CED_CODE   NAME    2011_POP    2012_POP`
`101    Banks   154938  156527`
electorates.geojson
`"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ELECT_DIV": "Lingiari", "STATE": "NT", "NUMCCDS": 335.0, "ACTUAL": 0.0, "PROJECTED": 0.0, "POPULATION": 0.0, "OVER_18": 0.0, "AREA_SQKM": 1352034.05, "SORTNAME": "Lingiari" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon",`
region.geojson
`"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "scalerank": 5, "featurecla": "Admin-0 country", "labelrank": 5.0, "sovereignt": "Australia", "sov_a3": "AU1", "adm0_dif": 1.0, "level": 2.0, "type": "Dependency", "admin": "Ashmore and Cartier Islands", "adm0_a3": "ATC", "geou_dif": 0.0, "geounit": "Ashmore and Cartier Islands", "gu_a3": "ATC", "su_dif": 0.0, "subunit": "Ashmore and Cartier Islands", "su_a3": "ATC", "brk_diff": 0.0, "name": "Ashmore and Cartier Is.", "name_long": "Ashmore and Cartier Islands", "brk_a3": "ATC", "brk_name": "Ashmore and Cartier Is.", "brk_group": null, "abbrev": "A.C.Is.", "postal": "AU", "formal_en": "Territory of Ashmore and Cartier Islands", "formal_fr": null, "note_adm0": "Auz.", "note_brk": null, "name_sort": "Ashmore and Cartier Islands", "name_alt": null, "mapcolor7": 1.0, "mapcolor8": 2.0, "mapcolor9": 2.0, "mapcolor13": 7.0, "pop_est": -99.0, "gdp_md_est": -99.0, "pop_year": -99.0, "lastcensus": -99.0, "gdp_year": -99.0, "economy": "7. Least developed region", "income_grp": "5. Low income", "wikipedia": -99.0, "fips_10": null, "iso_a2": "-99", "iso_a3": "-99", "iso_n3": "036", "un_a3": "-099", "wb_a2": "-99", "wb_a3": "-99", "woe_id": -99.0, "adm0_a3_is": "AUS", "adm0_a3_us": "ATC", "adm0_a3_un": -99.0, "adm0_a3_wb": -99.0, "continent": "Oceania", "region_un": "Oceania", "subregion": "Australia and New Zealand", "region_wb": "East Asia & Pacific", "name_len": 23.0, "long_len": 27.0, "abbrev_len": 7.0, "tiny": -99.0, "homepart": -99.0 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates":`

now that ive written that out (and figured out how to do basic markdown in Stackoverflow like a clown), i wonder, is it getting caught up on the join of the name in region.geojson?

thx much for the help @mbostock

Comment: Can you share the first two lines of the TSV file (most importantly the column names and one sample of values), and one object each from the GeoJSON files (just the properties; no need to post the coordinates).

Comment: after fumbling around for like 15 minutes, i've updated the above question instead of trying to do it here in the comments (as i assume you should.) thx @mbostock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so embarrassingly (as this has happened before to me), this was because i was using an outdated version of topojson.

after i updated the version to 1.2.3 (using `npm update -g topojson`) the properties mapped appropriately with the above command.

thx for responding regardless mike. i feared it was something on my end. alas, it was.